# Html.DropdownListFor troubleshoot

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I'm trying to learn the syntax for DropDownListFor.

Given the following in a `for` loop:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(  
        model => model.SalutationID, Model.AvailableSalutations.Select(option => new SelectListItem 
        {
            Selected = (option.ID == staff.SalutationID),
            Text = option.Desc.ToString(),
            Value = option.ID.ToString()
        }
    ), 
    "Choose...")
```

... and given that staff.SalutationID does echo correct values (when, for example, I just use `@Html.ValueFor(model => staff.SalutationID)`), why does every dropdown echoed in my loop default to "Choose..." and not the `Selected` option?

Comment: it all looks right to me.  One thing you might try,  if model.SalutationID = staff.SalutationID the for helper should set the selected automatically and you shouldn't need to set it on the select list item.  You might try removing that and see if it makes any difference

Comment: @MattBodily No Matt, makes no difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What decides what is the selected option in the drop down list is the value of the model property specified by the lambda in the first parameter in the `Html.DropDownListFor`. In your case `model => model.SalutationID`.

Verify that `model.SalutationID` has the expected value in the model. If not, specify it in the controller's action, before rendering the view.

Comment: Do you mean to echo the value held by that lambda, to see if it is a) there and b) correct? If so, I have already tried `Html.ValueFor(model => staff.SalutationID)` within the loop, and the value shows correctly for each record... I don't know how else to verify it?

Comment: You got me working on it properly - I changed the lambda expression to `model => staff.SalutationID`, where `var staff = Model.AvailableStaffMembers[i];` within the loop. This makes it work. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend you to define the SelectLists directly as view model properties, and populate them in the action (controller's method). In this way it's easier to debug, unit test and modify the views without problems.

Comment: I have (I think!) done this. But I am in the very early stages of learning ASP MVC, and I find the documentation extraordinarily dense. So here I am :(

Comment: No, you haven't :) Perahps you are not even using view models. A view model is a class created specifically to act as a model for a view: it's the `model` when you return a `View("ViewName", model)`. You should always use these classes, and usually, some of the members of these classes will look like `public SelectList Salutations {get;set;}`, so your drop down list is rendered like this `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SalutationId, Model.Salutations)` We all once were novices.

Comment: Thank you for understanding! I'm obviously missing a step in my Controller so, as I have a ViewModel created - drawing from my Staff table and from my Salutation tables (`public List<Prm_Salutation> AvailableSalutations { get; set; }` and `public List<Prm_Staff> AvailableStaffMembers { get; set; }`). I use Linq to populate these in my Controller with records from my DB, then forward them on to the View...

Comment: You'd only have to take the extra step to convert those raw lists into SelectLists in the controller. In this way you send a "fully cooked" model to the view engine (ordered, formatted, etc.) In fact, it's good to have an "UI adapter layer". Your controller can use de Business Logic and the UI adapter to prepare the view models. For example, the BL returns a raw list of salutations, and the UI adapter create a well formatted and ordered SelectList ready to be used in a View. This makes it easier to reuse the logic that populates the SelectList in other controller/actions.

Comment: Didn't know about adapter layers. Thanks!